# PHP mail send random failure without changing the code "No recipient addresses found in header"

Tags: php, email, sendmail

### EDIT: After reviewing i found error in the loop, which is not related to the title. I'm leaving the code here so it can help others.

---

I wrote this code for sending an email, by pushing a button and it worked perfectly, but at some point it randomly stopped without me changing it, displaying error that doesn't make sense to me **`No recipient addresses found in header`**. Note that i have put `print $to;` at the end of the code so i can see what is being set to the variable. I get nothing. Empty space. `var_dump($to);` returns `NULL`

```
<?php 
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .  "/common/config.php"  ; 
$id = $_GET['id'];
$table = $_GET['table'];
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE loadID = '$id'");
while($f = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
$to = "noreply@example.com"; 
$subject = 'Dispatch information on Load: '.$f['loadnumber'].' for Truck: '.$f['trucknum']; 

$random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 

$headers .= "From: dispatch@example.com\r\nReply-To: dispatch@example.com"; 

$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-".$random_hash."\""; 

ob_start(); 
?> 


--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

EMAIL CONTENT GOES HERE

<?php } ?>
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--

<?php 
$message = ob_get_clean(); 

$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 

print $to;

?>
```

Comment: I am guessing your while loop, within which `$to` is defined, is not running.  You should add error handling around your database calls and see what is going wrong there. You also have a terrible dangerous script with significant SQL injection vulnerability (that is if your database connection works of course).

Comment: I understand what you're saying and indeed i saw i have an error in the loop by including the mail() function into it. But still the error itself occured with no change of the code and when i try `or die(mysql_error())` i don't get anything

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a couple of issues. First you are looping through and setting the $to and $header variables in each while iteration which is redundant and also filling up the $header variable with repeated content that is not necessary. It would also not send an email for each iteration, instead piling more and more into one single email with the possibility of it not being formatted correctly. Also, the $to parameter in the mail function is not the same as the "To:" header. It is likely a script or savvy admin caught on to that and require a "To:" header to be present in the email. Try this:

```
<?php 
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .  "/common/config.php"  ; 
$id = $_GET['id'];
$table = $_GET['table'];
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE loadID = '$id'");
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 

$to = "noreply@example.com"; 
$headers = "To: $to\r\n";
$headers .= "From: dispatch@eagleexpress05.com\r\nReply-To: dispatch@eagleexpress05.com"; 
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-".$random_hash."\""; 

while($f = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    $subject = 'Dispatch information on Load: '.$f['loadnumber'].' for Truck: '.$f['trucknum']; 

    ob_start(); 
    ?> 


    --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
    Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

    EMAIL CONTENT GOES HERE

    <?php
    --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--<?php
    $message = ob_get_clean(); 

    $mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
}

print $to;
?>
```